# Get dates between start and end in Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

In a fluid template I have a start date and an end date. How do I get the dates in between so I have a list of all dates?

```
<f:format.date format="%d">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>
<f:format.date format="%d">{newsItem.eventEnd}</f:format.date>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution for this but you can write your own viewhelper which takes these two `DateTime` objects and returns a [`DatePeriod`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) object which you can conveniently iterate with `<f:for>` in your template. For every iteration you get a `DateTime` object again which you can format as usual.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can create your own `ViewHelper` and in that you need to pass start and end dates and it will return `DatePeriod` object which you can iterate using for loop (`<f:for>`) in `Fluid` template.

You can try something like :

**Use `ViewHelper` in Fluid Template as :**

```
{namespace vh=Vendor\ExtensionKey\ViewHelpers}

<f:for each="{vh:DateRange(startdate:'{starttime}', enddate:'{endtime}')}" as="dates">
    <f:format.date format="%d.%m.%Y">{dates}</f:format.date> <br/>
</f:for>
```

**ViewHelper Class :**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ExtensionKey\ViewHelpers;

/**
* Date Range ViewHelper
*/
class DateRangeViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('startdate', 'string', 'start date', true);
        $this->registerArgument('enddate', 'string', 'end date', true);
    }

    /**
     * @return \DatePeriod $dateRange
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $startdate = new \DateTime($this->arguments['startdate']);
        $enddate = new \DateTime($this->arguments['enddate']);

        $interval = new \DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
        $dateRange = new \DatePeriod($startdate, $interval, $enddate);

        return $dateRange;
    }
}
```

References :

- https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/For.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I am new to ViewHelpers, one thing I don't understand is the `namespace` path. Do I point this to a fileadmin folder?

Comment: You need to create that in site config extension. Put it Under folder `Classes/ViewHelpers `. For namespace checkout : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Namespaces/Index.html